# mean and barplot failure with R 3.1.1

Tags: r, csv

I was working on R 2.11 on Mac, but I've installed the 3.1.1 version.

lala.csv is a data frame containing seven variables with 85 observations each, with some NAs

The following code was running perfectly :

```
lala <- read.table("lala.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", strip.white=TRUE, dec=".",
na.strings="NA")
mean(lala, na.rm=TRUE)
barplot(mean(lala, na.rm = TRUE))
```

but it's not anymore.

Now it's returning for mean ()

`In mean.default(lala, na.rm = TRUE) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

I have read about the fact that read.csv/table does not work as previous, so I tried

```
lala <- read.table("lala.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", strip.white=TRUE, dec=".", 
                   na.strings="NA", colClasses=c("numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                 "numeric","numeric", "numeric", 
                                                 "numeric"))
```

but when I try

```
is.numeric(lala)
```

it's returning FALSE

Finally, it worked with the following, and also with sapply

```
colMeans(lala, na.rm=TRUE)
barplot(colMeans(lala, na.rm=TRUE))
```

But for me it's a non-sense that the function mean does not work anymore on data frames.
Is there an other way to get what I had ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain what's so terrible about having to update your code to use `colMeans()` instead of `mean()` ... ?  (Do you have a giant code base that would be difficult to update, or are you otherwise restricted from updating it?)  If you *really* want to you could write your own `mean` function that would mask the one in base R, but it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: read `?mean` specifically the description for the x parameter; or create your own mean for data frames, as @BenBolker pointed out, `mean.data.frame <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) colMeans(x, na.rm)`, then `mean(lala, na.rm = TRUE)` would work as expected

Comment: @BenBolker yes first reason :). I will stand with colMeans(), I was just wondering if there was a way to make things work as previous for example when invoking read.table. Thank you ! also rawr

Answer (score 1):

Between then and now the R-Core decided to get rid of `mean.data.frame`. They gave warnings (whenever it was used) that it was deprecated across several versions and then finally killed it off (several versions ago). If you don't update regularly, then you don't see the warnings. (It has nothing to do with being  on a Mac nor is R 3.1.1 for SnowLeopard any different in this regard than 3.1.1 for Mavericks.)